# Getting error that unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 135

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am new to hibernate and trying to run query in hibernate but i am getting the exception that

```
unexpected token: ON near line 1, column 135 [SELECT A.comp_id.appRefNo ....
```

Here is the code

```
StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer("SELECT A.comp_id.appRefNo, 
    A.comp_id.custId from ");

query.append(LosaCustContactZ.class.getName());

query.append(" A INNER JOIN " + LosaCust.class.getName() + " B 
    ON ( B.comp_id.appRefNo = A.comp_id.appRefNo AND " + 
    "B.comp_id.custId = A.comp_id.custId) INNER JOIN " + LosaApp.class.getName() + " C 
    ON " + "(B.comp_id.appRefNo = A.comp_id.appRefNo) ");

query.append("WHERE C.comp_id.appRefNo != ?" + " AND C.appDt >= ? AND 
    A.contactT = 'PHONE'" ); 

if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(phoneNums)) {
    query.append(" AND A.contact IN(" + phoneNums + ")");
}

List<LosaCustContactZ> resultList = null;
try {
    resultList = getHibernateTemplate().find(query.toString(), 
           new Object[] { appRefNo, appDate });
} catch (Exception e) {
    String message = e.getMessage();
System.out.println();
}
return resultList;
```

what i am doing wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like there is a mapping association missed in your `hbm.xml.`

Please refer this.

[No defined association in hbm.xml file](http://www.jumpingbean.co.za/blogs/mark/hibernate)

Comment: Yes i don't have any association in my LosaCustContactZ.hbm.xml. When i run this query in sqlDeveloper then it runs, i mean by converting this to sql, but i think here i am using `B.comp_id.appRefNo = A.comp_id.appRefNo` but A(LosaCustContactZ) has no association in its.hbm.xml file.

Comment: So you got why we are facing with hibernate?

Answer (score 8):

Many constructs from SQL cannot moved one-to-one to the HQL. In HQL keyword `WITH` is used instead of `ON`, when joining with specific condition. This construct is specific to Hibernate and is not expected to work with other JPA providers.

[Chapter about HQL](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html) and especially [16.3 Associations and Joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins) in Hibernate Core Reference Manual are worth of reading.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code after correcting tables/columns names:

```
public static List<Object[]> getTopRequests(int start, int end)
        throws Exception {
    List<Object[]> list = null;
    Session session = null;

    try {
        session = HibernateUtil.openSession();

        session.beginTransaction();

        Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT "
                + " tr.id as id, "
                + // Column 0
                " tr.amount as amount,"
                + // Column 1
                " tcp.phoneNum as phoneNum, "
                + // Column 2
                " trs.faTitle as faTitle, "
                + // Column 3
                " tr.createDate as createDate "
                + // Column 4
                " FROM TopRequest as tr " + " , TopCellPhone as tcp "
                + ", TopRequestState as trs  "
                + " WHERE tcp.tcpId = tr.tcpId "
                + " AND tr.trsId = trs.trsId  "
                + " ORDER BY tr.updateDate DESC");

        q.setFirstResult(start);
        q.setMaxResults(end - start);
        list = (List<Object[]>) q.list();

        session.getTransaction().commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        _log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    } finally {
        HibernateUtil.closeSession(session);
        return list;
    }
}
```