# QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

I have a query:

```
SELECT year_body.year, count(year_body.year) as toOrder 
FROM YearBody year_body 
LEFT JOIN session Session WITH year_body.sessionID = Session.sessionID 
LEFT JOIN version appVersion WITH session.applicationVersion = appVersion.version 
WHERE year_body.eventTime > :period and session.ipAddress NOT LIKE :ip and version.is_release = 1  
GROUP BY (year_body.year) 
ORDER BY toOrder DESC
```

This query works in MySQL workbench, but when I actually use it in Java I get the error:

```
QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join!
```

I have already got through other errors by switching `ON`s to `WHEN`s as well as fixing mapping issues but I am not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: ```WITH```? I think you mean ```ON```. You might also want to read up on what the different clauses mean, not just switch them when you have issues.

Comment: I got the change from this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15276136/getting-error-that-unexpected-token-on-near-line-1-column-135

If I use 'ON' instead of 'WITH' I get unexpected token 'ON'

Comment: Are you missing an ```ORDER BY year_body.year``` in there? ```DESC``` isn't for grouping.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Yeah that is there I just failed to copy it somehow, but that does not fix my error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to use a native query and my code works well after removing the object mapping references `SESSION` and `appVersion`